# Transform my if conditional to switch case with regex option: javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would like to transfer my if condition to switch case, because then it would look nicer in my code. (I have several switch case).
I can't set the switch parameter to true, because this will break the logic of my code.

```
 if (/(.*)_ERROR/.test(action.type)) {
    alert('ok'); //working
  }

  switch (action.type) {
    case /(.*)_ERROR/:
        alert('ok'); //not working
        break;
    ...
  }
```

How to write it? The idea is to enter the case only if the word "error" is in the string

Comment: How many other cases are there going to be?  A switch statement makes sense if there are many many different cases.  Using a switch for a single case doesn't make sense.

Comment: Afaik, the only way this works is `switch (true)` and `case /(.*)_ERROR/.test(action.type):` which is probably not what you're looking for. There's probably a better way to do this though, depending on what you're testing overall. For instance testing a string against multiple RegExps can be done by putting them in an array and using `Array.some()` or `Array.all()`: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/rfx1au6j/

Comment: @Taplar I  deleted unnecessary code ... there are 10+ cases

Comment: `case` only does `===` comparisons, it can't be used for arbitrary relationships.

Comment: BTW, you don't need `(.*)` in the regexp. Just `if (/_ERROR/.test(action.type))`

Comment: You can also write `if (action.type.includes('_ERROR'))`. You don't need a regexp if you're just looking for a fixed string rather than a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Not very ideal but you can use named groups:

```js
const reg = /(?<warning>(.*)_WARNING)|(?<error>(.*)_ERROR)|(?<info>(.*)_INFO)/; // warning, error, or info.
const match = action.type.match(reg);
if (match) {
   const groupName = Object.keys(match.groups).find(group => match.groups[group] !== null);
   switch (groupName) {
      case 'error': // like TEST_ERROR
      case 'warning': // like TEST_WARNING
      case 'info': // like TEST_INFO
      default:
   }
}
```